# Create a sparse symmetric random matrix in Julia

Tags: julia

is there an easy way to create a sparse symmetric random matrix in Julia?
Julia has the command

`sprand(m,n,d)`

which "Creates a [sparse] m-by-n random matrix (of density d) with iid non-zero elements distributed uniformly on the half-open interval [0,1)[0,1)." But as far as I can tell this doesn't necessarily return a symmetric matrix.

I am looking for an equivalent command to MATLAB's

`R = sprandsym(n,density)`

which automatically creates a sparse symmetric random matrix. If such a command isn't implemented yet, what would be a workaround to transform the matrix returned by `sprand(m,n,d)` into a symmetric one?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid extra memory caveat mentioned in the comment to Michael Borregaard's answer, the following function takes a sparse matrix and drops the entries in the lower triangular part. If the SparseMatrixCSC format is unfamiliar, it also serves as a good presentation of how the format is manipulated:

```
function droplower(A::SparseMatrixCSC)
    m,n = size(A)
    rows = rowvals(A)
    vals = nonzeros(A)
    V = Vector{eltype(A)}()
    I = Vector{Int}()
    J = Vector{Int}()
    for i=1:n
        for j in nzrange(A,i)
            rows[j]>i && break
            push!(I,rows[j])
            push!(J,i)
            push!(V,vals[j])
        end
    end
    return sparse(I,J,V,m,n)
end
```

Example usage:

```
julia> a = [0.5 1.0 0.0 ; 2.0 0.0 0.0 ; 0.0 0.0 0.0]
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.5  1.0  0.0
 2.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0

julia> b = sparse(a)
3×3 SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64} with 3 stored entries:
  [1, 1]  =  0.5
  [2, 1]  =  2.0
  [1, 2]  =  1.0

julia> c = droplower(b)
3×3 SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64} with 2 stored entries:
  [1, 1]  =  0.5
  [1, 2]  =  1.0

julia> full(Symmetric(c))    # note this is symmetric although c isn't
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.5  1.0  0.0
 1.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: is c symmetric?

Comment: @Liso `c` is not symmetric, but `Symmetric(c)` is, and it doesn't waste storage space on the lower triangular part of the matrix (as I tried to convey in the first paragraph)

Comment: There is `triu` (coresponding to your `droplower`), and `tril` to get the upper or lower triangle. Similarly, there is also `triu!` and `tril!` that does the operations in place.

Comment: @fredrikekre Triu that! Thanks - it was logical to have such a function.

Answer (score 5):

You could `Symmetric(sprand(10,10,0.4))`

Comment: Thank you! Would the resulting matrix still be sparse? Or do I have to do ´´´sparse(Symmetric(randn(m,n)))´´´ ?

Comment: It would still be sparse. Symmetric matrix types wrap other matrices and ignore their lower triangular part. A little caveat would be the wasted memory used to store inaccessible entries in the sparse matrix underlying the Symmetric matrix.

Comment: @miga89 another caveat is the sparse matrix-vector product is slower after symmetriclize, refer to [this issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/22200) for further details.

Comment: An argument in favour of my suggested approach is that it's generic and will benefit from future improvements in support of symmetric sparse matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Operations on the SparseMatrixCSC often need to be customized for maximum efficiency. So, to get from a sparse matrix `A` to a symmetric sparse matrix with the same upper part, here is a custom version (it is a bit cryptic, but working):

```
function symmetrize(A::SparseMatrixCSC)
    m,n = size(A)
    m == n || error("argument expected to be square matrix")
    rows = rowvals(A) ; vals = nonzeros(A)
    a = zeros(Int,n) ; b = zeros(Int,n) ; c = 0
    for i=1:n
        for j in nzrange(A, i)
            if rows[j]>=i
                if rows[j]==i a[i] += 1 ; c += 1 ; end
                break
            end
            a[i] += 1 ; b[rows[j]] += 1 ; c += 2
        end
    end
    c == 0 && return SparseMatrixCSC(n, n, ones(n+1), nrows, nvals)
    ncolptr = Vector{Int}(n+1)
    nrows = Vector{Int}(c) ; nvals = Vector{eltype(A)}(c)
    idx = 1
    for i=1:n
        ncolptr[i] = idx
        if a[i]==0 a[i] = idx ; idx += b[i] ; continue ; end
        for j in (0:a[i]-1)+first(nzrange(A, i))
            nvals[idx] = vals[j] ; nrows[idx] = rows[j] ; idx += 1
            rows[j] >= i && break
            nvals[a[rows[j]]] = vals[j] ; nrows[a[rows[j]]] = i
            a[rows[j]] += 1
        end
        a[i] = idx ; idx += b[i]
    end
    ncolptr[n+1] = idx
    return SparseMatrixCSC(n, n, ncolptr, nrows, nvals)
end
```

And a sample run:

```
julia> f = sprand(5,5,0.2)
5×5 SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64} with 5 stored entries:
  [1, 1]  =  0.981579
  [3, 1]  =  0.330961
  [5, 1]  =  0.527683
  [4, 5]  =  0.196898
  [5, 5]  =  0.579006

julia> full(f)
5×5 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.981579  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     
 0.0       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     
 0.330961  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     
 0.0       0.0  0.0  0.0  0.196898
 0.527683  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.579006

julia> full(symmetrize(f))
5×5 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.981579  0.0  0.0  0.0       0.0     
 0.0       0.0  0.0  0.0       0.0     
 0.0       0.0  0.0  0.0       0.0     
 0.0       0.0  0.0  0.0       0.196898
 0.0       0.0  0.0  0.196898  0.579006
```

This version should be faster than others, but this still needs to be benchmarked (and some `@inbounds` added in the `for` loops).

Comment: You could comment that code on the issue Gnimuc linked - it reads as if that's the kind of thing they're thinking of implementing